# Sound does not work after last update (Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: sound

After last update the sound simply does not work on my computer (DELL Inspiron 17, 7000 Series). I have tried everything "standard", what I found on the internet like reinstalling alsa and using pavucontrol.

Any ideas what might help?